# update query python mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm doing a web scraping project and now I'm trying to store my data into a MySQL database (remote server).
I'm sure the DB config is done write, but I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:**\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    cnx.commit()
File "C:**\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 406, in commit
    self._cmysql.commit()
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

Here is my code (main.py):

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='XXXX', password='XXXXX',
                              host='XXXXXXXX',
                              database='sql4456946')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

maxID = ("SET @lastid = (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `stand`); "
         "UPDATE `stand` SET `price` = 9999 WHERE `id` = @lastid")
cursor.execute(maxID)
cnx.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a multiquery so you must use the parameter in the [connection string](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)

But you could make it in one query only

> ```
> CREATE TABLE stand(id int ,price DECIMAL(19,2) )
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO stand VALUES (1,100)
> ```

> ```
>     UPDATE `stand` SET `price` = 9999 WHERE `id` = (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM (SELECT `id` FROM `stand`)  st)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM stand
> ```
>
> ```
> id |   price
> -: | ------:
>  1 | 9999.00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1bb5d88ffbac243a768ede6d7e21f45c)*

Comment: I've checked the documentation and I still don't understand what is that "st" you added at the end of the query. Is it just to say it is a multiquery?
But it works now with it, thank you!

Comment: mysql doesn't like when you update a table and use it in a subquery, that is why you need a temporarytable which is created with (SELECT id FROM stand) st and st is that temporary table. to understand it further, an update changes rows so that the result of the subselect can change, a´the created temporary table is fixed and will not be changed by the update and it is now deterministic